# import product data to magentogo online store

Tags: magento

I tried to import the product data to my online store. I got the following errors..

Category does not exists in rows: 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 27, 28, 31, 35, 36, 39, 43, 51, 52, 59, 60, 63, 64, 66, 71, 72

Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows: 3, 9, 14, 18, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 63, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71

Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row errors in rows: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 64, 65, 66, 72

Errors limit (100) reached. Please fix errors and re-upload file

Checked rows: 72, checked entities: 27, invalid rows: 70, total errors: 100

Could you please tell me what is causing this?

Answer (score 6):

I faced same problems but i rectified them with following steps.

**Error-1**--Category does not exists in rows: 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 27, 28, 31, 35, 36, 39, 43, 51, 52, 59, 60, 63, 64, 66, 71, 72
**Solution**: The problem is the categories to which the products attached to are not present in the backend so create those categories. Once this done the error disappears

**Error-2** -- Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows: 3, 9, 14, 18, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 63, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71
**Solution**:`_attribute_set` column is a compulsory field it should be there with a value 
while uploading the products.

**Error-3** Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row errors in rows: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 52, 53, 54, 60, 61, 62, 64, 65, 66, 72 Errors limit (100) reached. Please fix errors and re-upload file Checked rows: 72, checked entities: 27, invalid rows: 70, total errors: 100
**Solution**: This error disappears once the two above is fixed.

Thank you.
Happy coding.

Comment: You can export the csv file from Magento and then replace everything with product details that you are trying to upload/import. You can also leave out fields that are not important like allow_message, email_template etc.